# How to secure requests or/and responds from server

Tags: php, angularjs, api, security, request

I have AngularJS + Php application, developed an API in php which handles requests and retrieves data. The problem is that steal my data analysing requests.

Are there any ways to secure my data? Maybe I need to use using encryption on server and decryption on client-side of application? Are there any reliable ways to do it?

Data was collected by 4 employees for several months and I'm very concerned about the safety of my data.

Comment: I'm confused. By placing your data behind a publicly available API, isn't your intent to share it? Are you hoping to only share it to certain people (like those with a user name and password?) in which case, you need to look into authentication.

Comment: How many people need access to this data?

Comment: The data must be public, but I would like to prevent gathering data using parsers...

Answer (score 0):

May be, you must use https protocol?